# Ktor: Serializer for class ‘JsonLiteral’ is not found

Tags: kotlin, serialization, ktor, ktor-client

Updated my **Ktor client** from 1.6 to 2.3.0 and GET requests are fine but POSTs have this error:

> Serializer for class ‘JsonLiteral’ is not found. Please ensure that
> class is marked as ‘@Serializable’ and that the serialization compiler
> plugin is applied.

With Ktor 2.0.0 this error is:

> No request transformation found: {“search”:{“dates”:“current”}}

I use `kotlinx.serialization`.

**Ktor**

```
val httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
        expectSuccess = false
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                encodeDefaults = false
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                isLenient = true
                useAlternativeNames = false
            })
        }
        install(Logging) {...}
    }

suspend fun post(url: String, headersMap: Map<String, String>, data: Any) = coroutineScope {
    return@coroutineScope httpClient.post(url) {
        for (element in headersMap) header(element.key, element.value)
        setBody(data)
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
fun sendPost() = runBlocking{
    val requestData = "{\"search\":{\"dates\":\"current\"}}"
    val json = Json.parseToJsonElement(requestData)
    val result = Ktor.postAsync<HttpResponse>("http://127.0.0.1:8080", requestHeaders, json)
    assertEquals("", result.toString())
}
```

Comment: Can you double-check that you send the `Content-Type` header with the `application/json` value in the request?

Comment: Yes, it's specified. Found an answer but there is long way to redesign all the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [manual](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#send_data), now it’s needed to send a whole data class instead of its JSON. You also need to specify `contentType`.

```
val response: HttpResponse = client.post("http://localhost:8080/customer") {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(Customer(3, "Jet", "Brains"))
}
```